# Data freshness in production

Tags: amadeus

I would like to know about the freshness of **Inspirationnal search and flightOfferSearch** endpoint.

I would like to implement some caching mechanism for performance and to not make redundant call to your api when not required.

how many time could I put the inspirationnal Search and flightOffer Search response in cache before refreshing the results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flight Inspiration Search**: The API is built on top of a cache, you can cache those prices on your side as they are not refreshed all the time. Regarding how often you should refresh the cache: there is no golden rule, some prices/availabilities are refreshed a few times a day, some once a day or every few hours... In any case, this is an inspirational API, you should always call **Flight Offers Search** when you select one of the offer returned by **Flight Inspiration Search** to get the latest price/availability.

**Flight Offers Search**: This API doesn't have a cache, you get the latest prices and availabilities every time you call the API. Prices and availabilities in flights are changing quite a lot and there is no specific rule to ensure you have the updated data (the only ways are to either call the search again or to call **Flight Offers Price** to refresh a specific list of flight offers). You can build a cache but you will have to refresh it very often if you want accurate data.

Note: You are allowed to cache only to improve the performances of your solution, not to store and resell the data.